# If f is continuous at a and f(a) > 0, then there is δ > 0 such that f(x) > 0 for all x ∈ dom(f) with |x − a| < δ

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm having trouble proving this statement especially because I am not fully convinced it is true.

"If f is continuous at a and f(a) > 0, then there is δ > 0 such that
f(x) > 0 for all x ∈ dom(f) with |x − a| < δ"

I know that given that f is continuous at a, for any >0, there exists  such that for any |−|<, |()−()|< holds, i.e., there exists an open interval =(−,+), such that for any ∈, |()−()|< holds.

Do I need to show that f(x) is within the interval for a carefully chosen δ? I am not sure where to go from here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As $f(a) > 0$ there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(a) - \epsilon> 0$ (Take, for instance, $\epsilon = \frac{f(a)}{2}$). From the definition of continuity, for such $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in Dom(f)$, $|x - a| < \delta$ we have $|f(a) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, which means that $0 < f(a) - \epsilon < f(x) < f(a) + \epsilon$. This is a particular case of the result which says that for every open set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ we have that $f^{-1}(A)$ is an open set.

Comment: So this means if f(a) could be 0, then this statement is not necessarily true?

Comment: Sorry, you wrote $f(a) > 0$, right? ($\epsilon = \frac{f(a)}{2}$ works because $f(a) > 0$, then in this case $\epsilon = \frac{f(a)}{2} > 0$) What you have, similarly is: If $f(a) < 0$ then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$, $x \in Dom(f)$ then $f(x) < 0$.

Comment: Yes you're correct on what I wrote, I was wondering if this changes if $f(a) \ge 0$

Comment: It changes a lot, actually. Take a look at the following exemples: $f, g, h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x^{2}$, $g(x) = -x^{2}$ and $h(x) = x^{3}$. In these examples $f,g,h$ are continuous and $f(0) = g(0) = h(0) = 0$, but the behavior of this functions near to $0$ are quite different.